# onclick handler not working on component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On my layout component, I have two methods which toggle a menu open or force it closed. The toggle method works like a charm, however I want the menu to close when the user clicks on anything inside the header (so the menu doesn't stay open from page-to-page). However that part doesn't seem to want to work and I can't tell why.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header.jsx';
import Footer from '../components/Footer.jsx';

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mobileMenuVisible: false
    }
  }

  handleNavClick() {
    // Check if the menu is visible and then toggle to the other state
    if(!this.state.mobileMenuVisible) {
      this.setState({mobileMenuVisible: true});
    } else {
      this.setState({mobileMenuVisible: false});
    }
  }

  forceCloseNav() {
    // Don't perform checks, just set the menu visibility to false
    this.setState({mobileMenuVisible: false});
  }

  render() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    return(
      <div class={'main menu-open-'+ this.state.mobileMenuVisible} role="main">
        <span class="header-toggle" onClick={this.handleNavClick.bind(this)}><div><span>Menu</span></div></span>
                <Header onClick={this.forceCloseNav.bind(this)}/>
        <div class="wrapper">
            { this.props.children }
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I've added console logs and I can see that the onClick handler on the  component doesn't fire at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All looks correct in your example. But, can you check, how do you handle `onClick` in your `<Header />` component? It's a custom component, probably there are no clickHandlers there.

Below, you can see a working example with html `<header>` (press `run`)

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mobileMenuVisible: false,
    };
  }
  
  handleNavClick() {
     console.log('Nav open');
     this.setState({mobileMenuVisible: true});
  }
  
  forceCloseNav(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Nav close');
    this.setState({mobileMenuVisible: false});
  }
  
  render() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    return(
      <div class={'main menu-open-'+ this.state.mobileMenuVisible} role="main">
        <span class="header-toggle" onClick={this.handleNavClick.bind(this)}><div><span>Menu</span></div>             </span>
                <header onClick={this.forceCloseNav.bind(this)}>Header content</header>
                
   
        <div class="wrapper">
            { this.props.children }
         <hr />
         { this.state.mobileMenuVisible ? 'Menu Visible' : 'Menu Hidden'}
        </div>
        <footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah yeah it is a custom component and as all I want to do is update the state, I didn't realise I'd have to add anything inside that component. I've updated my code to match your forceCloseNav() method but it doesn't seem to have made a difference (probably because mine is custom), is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: ah! I've fixed it, I just added `onClick={this.props.onClick}` to the header component. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Exactly! `
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <header onClick={this.props.onClick}>Hey, this is custom header</header>
  }
}
`

Comment: I'm not as rubbish at React as I thought! :P Thanks very much for your help. I've accepted your answer as the correct one :)